# Parsing all specific key values from JSON and putting them in a list?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "ID": "42871",
   "playerid": "226790",
   "position": "CDM",
   "resource_id": "50558438",
   "playername": "Onyinye Ndidi",
   "common_name": "Ndidi",
   "club_name": "Leicester City",
   "nation_name": "Nigeria",
   "league_name": "Premier League",
   "ps_LCPrice": "72000",
   "pc_LCPrice": "85000",
   "xbox_LCPrice": "81500"
},
{
   "ID": "42871",
   "playerid": "226790",
   "position": "CDM",
   "resource_id": "50558438",
   "playername": "Kai Havertz",
   "common_name": "Havertz",
   "club_name": "Bayer 04 Leverkusen",
   "nation_name": "Nigeria",
   "league_name": "Premier League",
   "ps_LCPrice": "44000",
   "pc_LCPrice": "55000",
   "xbox_LCPrice": "99000"
},
```

I want to get the output as this:

```
playername, xbox_LCPrice
playername, xbox_LCPrice
```

So it does the first array then the second one and keeps going to the end, how would I do that?

Comment: Show more code, comment why you did what. Just now I don't know filename .json etc. It's helpful to help when you see something that's maybe sooo close but don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with open(config_file) as f:
    config_dict = json.load(f)

player_name = config_dict['playername']
```